# Team site - Different view / web parts based on what stage the team members are in

Tags: 2013, list-view, view, team-sites, team

Is there a way to use the same team site to show different:

- document library(s)
- webparts (show / hide)
- documents
- timeline
- etc

based on different phase / stage the team site is in?

Based on what phase / stage the team members need to view different information, what I was thinking about is to view / show different webpart / documentlibrary based on a filter on the page. Filter is based on URL

Comment: This is an interesting question.  How are you tracking the site's phase?

Comment: Team site administration can maby change what phase / stage .. maby by a dropdown . The value in the dropdown menu pushes back to a collected list over all the team sites and what stage the team site is in. 

Name              phase
teamsite1          2
teamsite2          4

Answer (score 1):

You can even do it in one webpart using XSLT, switching used templates based on a variable, like this:

```
<xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="$phase = 'A'">
        <xsl:call-template name="phaseA"/>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:when test="$phase = 'B'">
        <xsl:call-template name="phaseB"/>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:call-template name="phaseDefault"/>
    </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```

with phaseA, phaseB, phaseDefault as templates showing different data / different aspects relevant for the specific phase.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you want to configure what users see on a particular page, not throughout the whole site.  Given what I know about your problem, here's what I would do:

- Create a page for each status, and put the relevant content on each page.
- Create a "gateway" page, which users will navigate to
- On your gateway page, query the list that contains the current site's status.  You can do this a number of ways - application page using C#, custom web part, or just a site page using JavaScript. Personally, I'd use the site page/JavaScript approach.
- Fetch the site's status, and in code, redirect the user to the appropriate page.